# Get xmllint xpath soap

Tags: xml, parsing, soap, xmllint

I need to parse that xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body> <m:runResponse xmlns:m="http://www">
        <m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true;231;470;159;194;1439;476;637;99842;1164</m:return>
</m:runResponse></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and need to get

> true;231;470;159;194;1439;476;637;99842;1164

I do:

```
xmllint --xpath "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/m:runResponse/m:return" out.xml
```

and get result:

```
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
XPath evaluation failure
```

How I can parse it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='runResponse']/*[local-name()='return']/text()" file.xml
```

But I prefer `xmlstarlet` which I find somewhat easier:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" -N m="http://www" -t -v '//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/m:runResponse/m:return' file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can I do it in xmllint without local-name?

Comment: I don't think so. It's always rather difficult to work with namespaces and xmllint